# How do i fix errors in pandas lib while working in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I was trying out this ..sorting out the necessary data using pandas taking the data set from quandl. when  this showed up on execution.

```
import pandas as pd
import quandl
df = quandl.get('WIKI/GOOGL')
print(df.head())
df = df[['Adj. Open','Adj. High','Adj. Low','Adj. Close','Adj. Volume']]
print(df.head())
df['HL_PCT']=(df['Adj. High']- df['Adj. Close'])/df['Adj. close'] *100.0
df['PCT_change'] = (df['Adj .Close']-df['Adj. open'])/df['Adj. Open']*100.0
df = df[['Adj. Close','HL_PCT','PCT_change','Adj. Volume']]
```

[image]
so i got that as an error message

### update:

i updated my code with right capitalizing
now its got this as error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2656, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 108, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 132, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1601, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1608, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Adj .Close'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sentdex2.py", line 8, in 
    df['PCT_change'] = (df['Adj .Close']-df['Adj. Open'])/df['Adj. Open'] *100.0
  File "D:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2927, in **getitem**
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2658, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 108, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 132, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1601, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1608, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Adj .Close'

Comment: Please do not post errors as images

Answer (score 0):

Replace `Adj. close` with `Adj. Close` (note the capital `C`)